# How to serialise a Python dictionary to a JavaScript object text?

Tags: javascript, python, serialization

Can someone suggest a way to serialise a Python dictionary to JavaScript source code describing an equivalent object?

Note that this is different from JSON serialisation.  In particular, the following example is important to me:

```
x = { True: 1, False: 0 }
```

Serialising this with `json.dumps(x)` results in:

```
{ "true": 1, "false": 0 }
```

What I want is:

```
{ true: 1, false: 0 }
```

This is a valid object declaration in JavaScript but is not valid JSON.  Similar problems occur when using any non-string type as a dictionary key.

Comment: But what is the difference knowing that in JS keys are string type anyways?

Comment: @Andrey - that's not true.  It's perfectly valid to declare a JS object with boolean keys.  `x = { true: 1, false: 2 }; console.log(x[true]);` runs just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript object keys can only be strings or [Symbols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol)

You can access the object properties with true/false because javascript convert them to strings, you can see that they are actually string with:

```
var x = { true: 1, false: 0 }
console.log(Object.keys(x)) // ["true", "false"]
```